# Creating backends according to path

Tags: haproxy, consul

I am using HAProxy as a proxy server in front of Consul, a microservice registry. I use HAProxy to route traffic to a specific backend according to what type of node it is (what service it runs, is it active, what version it is, etc etc)

So far, I can use HAProxy to see what the path begins with, and route it to one backend eg.if the path begins with /blog, it'll go to the blog backend.

My question is, when there are multiple criterion to select a backend, how should I create said backends? Can I nest them in a way? Should I just exhaustive list all combinations of criteria and add a backend for that?

Comment: Your question seems a bit unclear, but I've attempted to address what it seems like you're asking. Please edit the question to clarify, if I have misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

A `backend` is one or more servers (services, endpoints) that can all handle the same set of requests.  You don't define backends based on what goes to them, but rather on what *can* go to them.

Example, if you have a set of servers that can serve several kinds of static assets, you wouldn't make a backend for javascript, another for CSS, another for images. You'd make one.

```
backend static-assets
    mode http
    server static-1 203.0.113.100:80
    server static-2 203.0.113.200:80
```

Then route the appropriate requests to that backend.

You can do this in several ways.

Anonymous ACLs, one per pattern:

```
frontend main
    mode http
    bind :80
    use_backend static-assets if { path_end .js }
    use_backend static-assets if { path_end .css }
    use_backend static-assets if { path_end .png }
```

Anonymous ACLs with explicit `||` (logical OR):

```
frontend main
    mode http
    bind :80
    use_backend static-assets if { path_end .js } || { path_end .css } || { path_end .png }
```

Or use named ACLs.  Each line in a named ACL is OR -- only one line needs to match for the ACL to match.

```
frontend main
    mode http
    bind :80
    acl is_static path_end .js
    acl is_static path_end .css
    acl is_static path_end .png
    use_backend static-assets if is_static
```

Or use any combination of these.

The first `use_backend` directive to match is the backend the request will go to -- they're processed in defined order.  No "nesting" should be necessary.

Comment: I see what you mean. Maybe I need to rethink how I use HAProxy.. I'm trying to basically define backends but also have descriptors for the backends.. so a static-assets backend but also a static-assets-version-5 backend if that makes sense.

Comment: @ThomasOo so v5 static assets would be handled by a completely different set of servers than, say, v4 assets?  Perhaps you could add an an example of how you're doing things currently, and then an explanation of what about that doesn't work the way you wish it would.

Comment: Another note, HAProxy runs very well on small servers, so sometimes it makes logical and cost sense to have more than one tier. I have cases where some requests pass through two or three tiers of HAProxy. e.g. front-end tier 1 HAProxy routes out all of `/api/*` to tier 2 HAProxy, which routes on specific paths inside `/api/`, so API reconfigurarions can't possibly break anything else handled in tier 1. Some of tier 2's back-end destinations may be a third tier of HAProxy for various reasons. It sounds inefficient but it performs very well, and has a clean separartion of concerns.

Comment: Yes. v5 and v4 would be handled by a completely different set of servers. I did actually think about going the multiple HAProxy server route but my concern is that the number of tiers would increase as you increase the number of "filters" if that makes sense?

Comment: My use case is using HAProxy as a proxy to serve multiple microservices. These microservices are tagged by their name, and any number of other tags such as version number, activity status, etc etc. I'd like HAProxy to route to the desired services given a desired specificity. If I don't care what version number I get, I'll leave it out and be routed to servers that match the rest of my request (say I put in the name, and activity status).
For now I am very naively creating backends with all combinations of tags. For now there's only 5~ tags so its not a lot but it is not very scalable